# Unable to create a project in Jira using api, I am getting 400 error code whenever I try to run this script. Could anyone help me resolving the issue

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

**Code :**

```
import requests
import json

client_id = "<client-id>"
access_token = "<access-token>"
url="https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/{0}/rest/api/2/project".format(client_id)
headers = {
           'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
             'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token),
       }

parameters= {
   "key": "EX",
   "name": "Example",
   "projectTypeKey": "business",
   "projectTemplateKey": "com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management",
   "description": "Example Project description",
   "lead": "Charlie",
   "url": "http://atlassian.com",
   "assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
   "avatarId": 10200,
   "issueSecurityScheme": 10001,
   "permissionScheme": 10011,
   "notificationScheme": 10021,
   "categoryId": 10120
}

response = requests.post(url, headers = headers,data = json.dumps(parameters))
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

**Output :**
{"errorMessages":["\'accountId\' must be the only user identifying query parameter in GDPR strict mode."],"errors":{}}

**Referencedocs api docs :**
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.12.0/#api/2/project-createProject

Answer (score 1):

While detailed documentation seems to be limited, in the `GDPR` world of today, you are expected to use the `leadAccountId` field. As for the value of this field, you can query it using the API or take the last URL element of the person's permission page (something like `https://<yoursite>.atlassian.net/jira/people/<accountId>`)

Comment: Not sure where you found that nugget, @gliptak, but it saved me hours. I find myself frequently exasperated at the state of some of the Atlassian documentation. Many thanks!